# Do I use one comma or two?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, commas

"I can tell who Hank and Bill are, but the fourth is missing, and the third's appearance is ambiguous."

Do I use the second comma or no? "The third's appearance is ambiguous," can stand on its own, but the "but" applies both to the second and third clause.

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Please take the [tour] and when you have a moment, read-up in the [help] about how we work.

Comment: It's not required to indicate parsing, but may be used if you prefer to indicate a pause (for emphasis or ease of reading, say). Purely a style choice.

Comment: I see you want to skip a comma to get the word *but* to apply to two clauses, and it may also be that the word *and* serves the same purpose (as this sentence). You might want to contrast the two halves (A, but B+C) using *but*, or you might allow the reader to figure out that the *and* clause offers perhaps additional information, perhaps contrasting.

Comment: There is a widely accepted practical exception to the general style rule that independent clauses should be set off with commas—and that exception arises when the independent clauses are quite short and the comma separator is not particularly helpful as a marker to help readers navigate the sentence. In your example, I find "but the fourth is missing and the third's appearance is ambiguous" to be at least as easy to parse as "but the fourth is missing, and the third's appearance is ambiguous," For that reason, I would be inclined to omit the comma after "missing."

Comment: I think the comma use here is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would put the comma before "and the third's appearance is ambiguous." You would put it there because it follows the rule of putting a comma before a coordinating conjunction that starts a new independent clause.

The list of coordinating conjunctions would be FANBOYS: for, and, but, or, yet, and so. You know to put a comma if there is a subject in the second part of the sentence. The sentence you said, "and the third's appearance is ambiguous," would have a subject, and it would be "the third's appearance" since it is the thing that is doing or being something.

You would not have a comma if there is no subject, however, like in this sentence,
"I can tell who Bill and Frank are, but the fourth is missing and is ambiguous." (something like this)

But yes, overall, you would include the comma because you always put a comma when joining two independent clauses with a coordinating conjunction. If the sentence is very short, you may be able to omit the comma, like in this sentence, "He ate the pasta and she drank the wine." But it would still be perfectly acceptable to include the comma in this sentence, and if you were trying to write formally, it's recommended that you still use the comma.